# Where and how many RCS thrusters are installed on Starship?

Tags: spacex, rockets, spacex-starship, rcs, position

Starship from SpaceX will soon launch. During the 10 km test it used RCS thrusters to flip itself in the right position. On the website it mentions how important it is to use air friction to slow down Starship and in order to do so will use RCS thrusters.

How many RCS thrusters are installed on Starship and where are they placed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Starship has 8](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/starships-rcs-thruster-system.1009641/#:%7E:text=Starship%20has%208%20sets%20of,the%20bottom%20near%20the%20base.). There are 4 at the top and 4 on the bottom. This configuration allow for guidance on all axis. They are also able to survive reentry due to their position on the craft.

Comment: can you add a bit more content?

Comment: What more is needed to answer the question? @TheRocketfan

Comment: you added a link. Maybe you can write a bit more about it or how the decision was made. Also what advantages are there having them in those positions.

Comment: Okay, I have @TheRocketfan

Comment: For example when Starship reenters the atmosphere, the rcs thrusters have to be protected from the heat. Where have they been placed in order to survive reentry.

Comment: Done @TheRocketfan

Comment: You just said they have been placed in order to survive reentry but it doesn’t answer where

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144718/discussion-between-the-rocket-fan-and-starship-is-go-for-launch).